# Como obter um retorno de uma Exception da WebApi?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-web-api

Tenho o seguinte método que faz uma requisição de `Delete` para a minha `WebApi`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id, IFormCollection frmCollection)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:6000/api/");
    var resposta = await httpClient.DeleteAsync($"cencus/{id}");

    //... TRATAR A EXCEPTION AQUI
}
```

O método de retorno da minha API é o seguinte:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public IActionResult Delete(int id)
{
  DatabaseConnector dbConn = new DatabaseConnector();
  try
  {        
    int affected = dbConn.Connection
        .Execute($"DELETE FROM CENCUS WHERE CODCEN = {id}");

    if (affected > 0)
    {
      return NoContent(); //203
    }
    else
    {
      return NotFound(); //404
    }        
  }
  catch (Exception exp)
  {
    return Conflict(exp); //409
  }
  finally
  {
    dbConn.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Minha dúvida é: em caso de `exception` na hora de executar o comando `SQL`, como vou acessar as informações como mensagem da `Exception` na resposta?

Comment: Retorne o status de erro e adicione a mensagem que deseja...

Comment: você aqui já envia o problema para sua WebApi (`return Conflict(exp); //409`) apesar que não sei se isso é bom ... !

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida, especificamente? Não dá pra entender o que você pretende fazer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade é mais simples do que eu imaginava, basta tentar converter o retorno e ver se a conversão foi um sucesso:

```
if (!resposta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Exception ex = await resposta.Content.ReadAsAsync<Exception>() as Exception;

    if (ex != null) {
        //O retorno da API foi uma exception...
    }
}
```